# Jackson JSON deserialization using static factory/parser method

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing, jackson

I need to deserialize something like the following (from JSON input):

```
class Container {
    M1 first;
    M2 second;
}
```

The problem is that I have no control over M1 and M2 but there are some methods provided by those classes: M1.fromJson(String input) that returns an M1 object and M2.fromJson(String input) that returns an M2 object. I would like to use those methods.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your string to a `Map<String, Map>` then manually call the `M1.fromJson` and `M2.fromJson` to build your `Container` as follow:

```
// You can use any json deserializer that you like insteaf of faster jackson
Map<String, Map> map = objectMapper.readValue(json);

Container container = new Container();
container.setFirst(M1.fromJson(map.get("m1")));
container.setSecond(M2.fromJson(map.get("m2")));

... // Use container as needed
```

Comment: Maybe I oversimplified the example but `Container` is part of a bigger datatype with some String etc. fields. That datatype could easily be deserialized with a single call of `objectMapper.readValue(...)` if there wasn't a Container field in it with the M1, M2 types.

Is it anyhow possible to rather write a JsonDeserializer for the MX types so they can be deserialized as part of any datatype (without manually having to care about m1, m2)?